# Can ArrayList handle big datasets in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I have a requirement to store around 100000 - 200000 records in a collection object. As of now, I am planning to use ArrayList, but I am interested to know the best way to store such a huge list.

Can any one of you help me come up with some thoughts on how to store large amounts of data into Collection? Which one is efficient, affordable in terms of performing well when it lands up in place?

ArrayList: Grows dynamically by allocating new memory chunks, potentially causing fragmentation. Is there any way we can define the size while creating the object itself? Is it the correct way to define ? Also do I need to change the java heap size ?

Is there any other data structure I should consider?

Note - I have decided to go with arraylist as order and index does not matter. I am fine with random access. I just want to know what are the best practice and other alternative approach.

Comment: How are you accessing the elements of the list? By index? By searching? Processing all of them?

Comment: When creating code, it helps to check the API.  *"Is there any way we can define the size while creating the object itself?"* [`ArrayList (int initialCapacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int))  It might help if you were to explore the [`Collection` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html). That page has links to various classes that implement that interface.

Comment: When choosing the appropriate data structure, you do so according to the requirements - what you need to do with the data stored, there is no such thing as best practices in this case. You never say what you are going to do with the data, so how are we supposed to answer this question effectively/correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling a large number of records efficiently involves choosing the right data structure. Here are simplified options:

#### ArrayList:

- Good for easy access by index.
- Set initial size to reduce resizing overhead: `ArrayList<Type> list = new ArrayList<>(initialCapacity);`
- Increase Java heap size if memory errors occur.

#### LinkedList:

- Efficient for adding/removing in the middle, but slow for random access.

#### HashSet/TreeSet:

- HashSet ensures uniqueness, TreeMap stores in sorted order.
- Useful for fast lookup but no inherent ordering in HashSet.

#### HashMap/TreeMap:

- Key-value pairs for fast retrieval by keys.

#### ArrayDeque:

- Good for queue (FIFO) or stack (LIFO) operations.

#### Considerations:

- Choose based on what you'll do most with the data.
- Think about memory usage versus performance.
- Check if you need to optimize for specific operations like lookup or insertion/removal.

#### Some insights you can consider:

- Preallocate space to reduce resizing.
- Increase Java heap size if needed for large datasets.

Comment: Linked list - `Efficient for adding/removing in the middle`, this is plain wrong, add/remove first/last is O(1), middle is O(n). HashMap and TreeMap is somewhat correct, but missing vital information - HashMap operations are generally O(1), but this depends heavily on good `hashCode()` implementation and correct `equals()` implementation. TreeMap operations are mostly O(log n), worse than HashMap, but keeps elements ordered.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have decided to go with arraylist as order and index does not matter. I am fine with random access. I just want to know what are the best practice and other alternative approach.

Comment: I understand @Chaosfire, but this is not about giving the breakdown of the Big(O) notation as Mario R has said he just wants to know the best practices and not the breakdown of the Big(O) notation between them as you can see I didn't bother to give that because Mario R just want to know the best practice. Anyways great input all the way

Comment: @FunmiAyinde For the most part your answer is giving out the time complexity, but without the Big O. I suppose this should help OP choose the correct data structure for his needs. If your information is **missing** important parts (hash/tree maps distinction) or is just completely **wrong** (linked list), how will he choose correctly?